Are all covalent compounds non-conductors of electricity?
According to my textbook:

The covalent compounds are said to be polar when the shared pair of electrons are not at equal distance between the two atoms. This results in the development of fractional positive and negative charges on them and they ionise in water.

Again while discussing about covalent compounds, it said:

Covalent compounds are non-conductors of electricity in solid, molten or aqueous state.

Another book even mentioned an experiment and gave this observation:

When the current is passed through the solutions of covalent compounds, i.e. distilled water, sugar solution, alcohol, chloroform, benzene and petrol the bulb doesn't glow. This shows that they don't conduct electricity.

Acidulated water (water mixed with acids like HCl and H2SO4), on the other hand, can conduct electricity.
Hence, is it appropriate to say that covalent compounds are non-conductors even in molten and aqueous state in a generalized manner?

Why do I have a downvote ? What's wrong with my question?

How would you call H2SO4 then? BTW it's acidified, not "acidulated".

H2SO4 is a polar covalent compound.

https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Acidulated_water    acidulated water do have a meaning

And its solutions sure do conduct electricity...

So, some polar compounds are capable of conducting electricity?

Even if you discarded it because it's mostly ions that conduct in such solution, there's still perfectly covalent graphite that conducts with its delocalised electrons well enough to make electrodes. So, no, it's not correct to generalise like that.

Silicon conducts, and in the molten state is metallic.

I think your textbook is unreliable. The first quote is nonsense. And the general idea that only things that ionise conducts is blatantly wrong as graphite conducts pretty well as others have pointed out.

Consider conductive polymers

Why am I still getting downvotes? The above-mentioned phrases aren't my assumptions...they have been mentioned in a book and I have raised my doubt about these. Moreover, I have got my answer. Seriously bcoz of these downvotes, I am not allowed to ask any question for now and have been suggested to wait for 2 days....

Polythiazyl, $\ce{(SN)_x}$, is an example of a covalently bonded polymer that is electrical conducting. Indeed according to the linked wikipedia article "Due to its electrical conductivity, polythiazyl is used in LEDs, transistors, battery cathodes, and solar cells", and at low temperature it becomes superconducting.

Covalent compounds with macromolecular structures are often semiconducting. Setting aside single elements, an obvious example is provided by gallium arsenide,, whose semiconducting properties are used in electtonic devices

such as microwave frequency integrated circuits, monolithic microwave integrated circuits, infrared light-emitting diodes, laser diodes, solar cells and optical windows.

Various other compounds of post-transition elements with similar stoichiometry, such as cadmium telluride, show similar charactetistics.
Cited Reference

Moss, S. J.; Ledwith, A. (1987). The Chemistry of the Semiconductor Industry. Springer. ISBN 978-0-216-92005-7.


As per some sites, Gallium arsenide and cadmium telluride are partially ionic and partially covalent. Is there any compound which is completely covalent and polar (or may be non-polar; although non-polar compounds don't ionise in water) which conducts electricity?

Partially ionic and partially covalent. Like everything, really?

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/S0076695X08600125                          AccordinglyI
the unequal sharing of charge between the Cd atom and Te
atomI with slightly more to the anion Te makes the bonding
to be ionic. Besides being ionic, show the bond paths (the lines along the top of density
ridges between the Te and Cd nuclei) that coincide with the
contours of electron sharing. These bond paths indicate the
molecule is slightly covalent

@Kakiaririki graphite is not polar and not remotely ionic. But it conducts electricity well as do many polymers with delocalised electron systems.
